# Density of a set and an approximating sequence

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^d,$ we define its density as
$$D(A)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|A\cap B_n|}{n^d}$$
where $B_n$ is the ball (w.r.t. the sup-norm) of radius $n$ centered in $0$ and $|A|$ is the cardinality of $A.$

Suppose that $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^d$ is a set with density $\alpha>0$ and $(C_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an increasing ($C_n\subseteq C_{n+1}$) sequence of set such that

$$C_n\subseteq B_n,$$

and

$$C:=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}C_n=A$$

Is true that exists $N>0$ such that for all $n\geq N,$
$$\frac{|C_n|}{n^d}\geq\beta>0?$$

If not, fiind a counterexample.

Comment: I would hazard no, the idea being that if $C_n$ approaches $A$ slow enough, then we may have $|C_n|/n^d$ approach $0$.

Comment: I think that this is possibile just on a subsequence of $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $C_n$ be the first $n$ points of a spiral the emanates from the origin $(0,0)$ and goes through every integral point on the plane. Think of the spiral as in the following image:

[image]

Then it's easy to check that we have $\alpha=1$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{C_n}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$, which means this is a counter-example.